# align text center with icon next to it

Tags: css

I have the following code:

```
<div class="icon-search small-collapse large-2 medium-12 small-12 hide-for-medium-down js-hide-for-small columns">
    <input type="submit" value="{{ 'SEARCH'|trans }}" class="button">
</div>
```

and the CSS for the icon is:

```
.icon-search:before{
  top: 15px;
  left: 18px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2.2rem;
}
```

however the value I get from "value='{{ 'SEARCH'|trans }}'" is dynamic because of the language selection.

How can I make sure that the "icon-search" is always 5px away from the value return from "{{ 'SEARCH'|trans }}" and that both are always aligned centered?

Comment: A demo might be useful because it's a little hard to understand what the issue is without seeing it.

Comment: `icon-search` is a background image? It might be hard to make your background image aware of your dynamic content. You may have to make your icon an actual html element and set static dimensions. Like `<i class="icon-search"></i>` next to your input.